# Trigonometric ratio question..

Tags: trigonometry

> If $3\sin B+5\cos B=5$, show that $3\cos B- 5\sin B=\pm 3$

I tried this:
\begin{align*}
3\sin B + 5\cos B & = 5\\
\text{or}, \dfrac{3p}{h} + \dfrac{5b}{h}& = 5\\
\text{or}, 3p+5b& = 5h\\
\text{or}, 9p^2+30pb+25b^2 & =25(p^2+b^2)\\
\text{or}, 16p^2& =30pb\\
\text{or}, \dfrac{p}{b}& =\dfrac{15}{8}
\end{align*}

$h= \sqrt{15^2+8^2} = 17$
\begin{align*}
LHS & = 3\cos B-5\sin B\\
    & = \frac{3b}{h}-\frac{5p}{h}\\
    & = \frac{3 \cdot 8-5 \cdot 15}{-17}\\
    & = -3
\end{align*}

But how do I get plus $3$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks I will learn it

Comment: What in the world are $ p $, $ b $, and $ h $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

$$25 = (3\sin B+5\cos B)^2= 9\sin^2B + 25\cos^2 B +15\sin2B \tag 1$$

and

$$(3\cos B- 5\sin B)^2= 9\cos^2B + 25\sin^2B -15\sin2B \tag 2$$

Substitute $\sin2B$ of (1) into (2) to get

$$(3\cos B- 5\sin B)^2= 9\cos^2B + 25\sin^2B -(25 - 9\sin^2B - 25\cos^2 B ) = 9$$

Thus,
$$3\cos B- 5\sin B=\pm 3$$